# Xcode 4.2 & ios5 cannot debug with jail broken device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I have jailbroker iphone 4 with ios5 and xcode 4.2. The problem is that I cannot debug with my device, this is what i get:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Fri Sep 16 06:56:50 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys002
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-8054-61
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of MobileSubstrate.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of SubstrateLoader.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/3GMy3G.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of 3GMy3G.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A334)/Symbols/usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libsubstrate.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A334)/Symbols/usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Applications/My3G.app/xyzzy.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of My3G.app/xyzzy.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
2011-11-14 12:23:44.234 Paragonex[9765:707] My3G waiting for User Prompt in com.paragonex.ubinary  v5.0..
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of Activator.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/DisplayOut.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of DisplayOut.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/pue.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of pue.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A334)/Symbols/usr/local/iphone/lib/libcups.2.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of libcups.2.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Applications/TruPrint.app/TruPrintDaemonClient.dylib (file not found).
warning: No copy of TruPrint.app/TruPrintDaemonClient.dylib found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
Program ended with exit code: 45
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I have the seem problem with my iPhone 4s iOS 5.0.1
The emergency method is download a app names respringIcon in Cydia, and when you want debug,open the app choose Safe Mode. App can debug in Safe Mode.
-----------update-------------
I had update to iOS 5.1.1 with jailbreak,and when I install one software from Cydia I use xCode to debug on phone, but no one make debug not work. I think iOS5 jailbreak had solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

This page http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=398 seems to have the same problem you're describing, and the answer (from that page) appears to be to set up an 'Override' in your Backgrounder.

I have no idea what that means - but it's what the page describes in order to work around the problem.

As always, the only way to "fix" this, is to not use a jailbroken device.

Comment: explanation of the override here: http://www.alexwhittemore.com/backgrounder-build-run/

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, it turned out TruPrint (which it seems you have installed) was causing problems with the XCode debugger. Try uninstalling it, rebooting the device and then try launching from XCode, it should work.